# Are there any real benefits to using a RDBMS vs. flat files on a simple Web doc system (or basic CMS)?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, content-management-system

**The Project**

I've been asked to work on an interesting project -- what amounts to a basic Web CMS -- that uses HTML/CSS/jQuery with PHP. However, one requirement is that there won't be a database to house the data (they want flat files for the documents/pages -- preferable in JSON format).

In a very basic sense, it'll be used to generate HTML pages via a very "non-techie" interface. Each installation would only have around 20 pages, but a few may get up to 100. It has to be fairly easy to drop onto a PHP capable server and run, with very little setup needed.

**What's Out There**

There are tons of CMS options and quite a few flat file versions. But an OSS or other existing CMS is not an option. They need a simple propriety system.

**Initial Thoughts**

So flat files it is... but I'd really like to get some feedback on the drawbacks, and if it is worth the effort to try and convince them to use something like MySQL (SQLite or CouchDB are out since none of the servers can be configured to run them at the present time).

Of course the document files are pretty straightforward, but we're also talking about login info for 1 or 2 admins per installation, a few lists, as well as configs/settings (which also can easily be stored in a file with protection).

**The Dilemma**

If there are benefits to using MySQL rather than JOSN formatted files and some arrays in a simple project like this -- beyond my own pre-conceived notions :) -- I'll be sure to argue them.

But honestly I can't see any that outweigh their need to not have a database system.

I'd appreciate you insight and opinions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't cite a specific need for relational table design, then you're good with flat files.  Build as specified.  The moment you can cite a specific need, let them know; upgrading isn't that hard, if you're perception is timely (that is, if you aren;t in the position of having to normalize data that should have been integrated earlier).

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame you can't use [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), this seems like the perfect application for it. Keep in mind that using flat-files severely constrains your architecture and, especially, scalability.

What's the best case scenario for your CMS app? It's successful and people want to use it more? If you're using flat-files it'll be harder to service and improve your system (e.g. make it more robust, and add new features for future versions) and performance will not scale well. So "success" in this case is at best short-lived, as success translates into more and more work for less and less gains in feature-set and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Then again, if the CSM is designed right, then switching between a flat file to RDMS should be as simple as using a different data access file.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be installed on any shared hosting sites. For this to work somewhat safely, a mechanism like [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) needs to be set up properly as the web server will need write permissions to various directories.

Answer (score 0):

What would be cool with a simple site that was feed via JSON and jQuery is that the site wouldn't need to load on each click.  Just the relevant data would change.  You could then use hashes in the location bar to keep track of where you were (ex. http://localhost/#about)

The problem being if they are editing the raw JSON file they can mess it up pretty quick.  I think your admin tools would have to generate the JSON files based on the input so that you can ensure nothing breaks.  The admin tools would be more entailed then the site (though isn't that always the case with dynamic sites)

Comment: Way too many sites do this because it's 'cool'. There is little to no benefit, especially on a traditional content publishing site.

Comment: but he's not talking about a traditional CMS...he's talking about a proprietary system that holds it's data in flat files.

Answer (score 0):

What is the predicted data sizes for the CMS?

A large reason for the use of a RDMS is quick,specific access to large amounts of data. The data format might not be large, but if there is a lot of the data, then it might be better in the long run for a RDMS.

Then again, if the CSM is designed right, then switching between a flat file to RDMS should be as simple as using a different data access file.

Answer (score 0):

While an RDBMS may be necessary for a very large CMS, a small one could run off flat files very well. A lot of CMS products out there fall down in that regard, I think, by throwing an RDBMS into the mix when there's no real need.

However, if you are using flat files, there are security issues which others have highlighted. Another issue I've come across is hosting providers using the [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.disable-functions) directive in php.ini to disable file I/O functions like fopen() and friends. If you're hosting your CMS on a box you control, you won't have this problem but if you're using a third-party provider, check first.

Answer (score 0):

As the original poster, I wasn't signed in, so I'm following up to the answers so far in an answer (sorry if this is bad form).

- There may instances where this is on
  a shared host.
- Though the JSON files can technically
  be edited, this won't be the case.
  The admin interface will be robust
  enough to do all of the creating/editing of pages
- The size for each install will be
  relatively small -- 1 - 2 admins,
  10-100 pages. A few lists of common
  items may run longer (snippets of
  copy for example).
- Security will be a big issue -- any
  other options suggestions on this
  specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't there a problem with they being distrustful to any database system? Isn't the problem more in their thinking than in technology? Maybe they are afraid of database because it sounds complex to them. In that case, if you just present them some very simple CMS (like CMS made simple, which I've heard is really simple and the learning process is very fast), if they see everything is easy then may be they just don't care what's behind, if it's a database or whatever!

They could hear to arguments like better maintenance, lower cost of maintenance, much better handover to another webmaster than proprietary solutions (they are not dependent on you) etc.